# When are hyphenated tags useful and when should they be removed in favor of single tags?

Tags: support, tags

I'm toying around with [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter) a lot and I check the created tags once in a while to make sure there are no strays. We have a lot of hyphenated tags like [flutter-something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-something). For some, it is obviously a good thing. Obviously [flutter-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-3) is a good tag compared to [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter)[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3) which would be pointless.

However, there are a lot of tags that I think could be "dehyphenated" and just the separate tags be used. One such example would be [flutter-apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-apk). There is nothing special about a Flutter APK. I would expect the question to be tagged [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter)[android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)[apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apk) for problems with building Android APKs for the flutter project.

None of the questions I checked are short of room for more tags. They could easily be dehyphenated.

Is there a guideline, when a new hyphenated tag is in order and when the old single tags are sufficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is, and you already know it and applied it here: When there is nothing special about the hyphenated term as opposed to the two terms applied separately.

If [flutter-apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-apk) is not special, then there's no reason to have [flutter-apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-apk). You should just have [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter) and [apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apk).

Comment: Just be careful and make sure you have or have consulted with someone who has domain knowledge before making a decision. You might assume [tag:python-unittest] is just equal to [tag:python] + [tag:unit-testing] but it's actually about a specific library, for example.

Comment: @ErikA also something that has been bothering me [fetch] + [api] when the question uses [the Fetch API in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) the correct tag is [[tag:fetch-api]]. And both of the other tags are rather unspecific by themselves.

Comment: Yup, that's why I'm in favor of specific tag names (e.g. js-fetch-api, python-unittest-lib, etc) but that's a different discussion. The model where a random user chooses a tag name and we have to either stick with it or involve meta and mods is not really optimal for the scale of SO, imo.